# Jquery child selector vs. .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Given the following example table:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What are the differences between:

```
$selector1 = $('ul.topnav > li');
```

and

```
$selector2 = $('ul.topnav').each();
```

EDIT:

$selector2 = $('ul.topnav li').each();

Comment: `$selector2 = $('ul.topnav').each();`
 With this , if you have lots of `ul.topnav` you just reference to them all / separately. Using `$selector1 = $('ul.topnav > li');` you access the DOM for all *children LI of .topnav* . Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first will contain all `li`'s which are a direct child of `ul.topnav`, the second will contain all `ul.topnav` elements.

Answer (score 1):

`$('ul.topnav > li')` will select all `<li>`s directly under the `ul`.

`each` should take a function as a parameter, and iterate over all matched `<ul>` - it doesn't not take the children `<li>`s. If anything, you want `$('ul.topnav').children()`, which is identical if the `ul` only contains `li` elements anyway.

For example, this will `alert` the number of children each list has (in your case, only the number `3`)

```
$selector2 = $('ul.topnav').each(function(){
   alert($(this).children().length);
});
```

Also see the [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/each).

Answer (score 0):

The second one will evaluate them individually, whereas the first one will evaluate them as a group